# PDF file download not working only for iPad specific browsers

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, pdf, safari

A PDF file is generated on server side and pushed to client end for download. While the download works in all browsers on windows , fails on IPAD. 
Please advise.

Specification : OS 6, Safari 6.1 , Chrome 23.0.1271.100

Please note: In this application pdf is not downloaded on to a new url (NO REDIRECTION).

General behavior: IPad browser (safari / chrome) does not support the download window, hence its expected to open the pdf and provides option to view in pdf compatible apps. Which is not currently happening.

When i debug the below servlet action code for download, the pdf file is successfully generated on server but browser on Ipad does not show :-(

Code sample :

/** Setting response Header **/

```
      response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=sample.pdf"); 
      response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
      response.setHeader("Cache-Control","cache");
      response.setHeader("Pragma","cache");
      response.setDateHeader ("Expires", dt.getTime() + 100000);
```

/** Writing to output **/

```
      InputStream stream = info.getInputStream(); 
      OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
      try {
            response.setContentType(contentType);
            copy(stream, response.getOutputStream());
      }
      finally {
      if (stream != null) {
         stream.close();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

After testing, the download action code pasted above  appeared to be working fine as the issue was BROWSER specific.

Andriod Tablet - Firefox browser downloads the pdf onto pop up window.
IPad : Safari - FIX: Forced the content to open up in a new tab, something like this :

**window.open(print_url);**

where print_url is the baseurl+action.do+additional_parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To display a pdf instead of asking the browser to save it, use "inline" instead of "attachment".

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=sample.pdf");
```

Also, you're setting content type twice, once in the header and once using `setContentType()`.
I'm not sure if those two headers interact or cancel each other out, so can't say for sure that it's a source of error, but it seems like something to consider changing.

Comment: 1. Content-Disposition "inline" does seem to work on OS. Tried it on Safari & chrome browsers.
2. Interesting point is setHeader(Content-Type,xxx) v/s setContentType
   Did try out the permutations & combinations did not help in Ipad but on windows firefox clearly showed setContentType is must.
   
   My issue is still not resolved. Your insight would be of great help.